# simple c++ "hello world" wont run with this error (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-code, g++

hello i just want to compile this simple c++ code with vscode

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"hi";
    return 0;
 }
```

and i try to compile it with this command

```
g++ main.cpp
```

BUT i get this error !

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
    (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I've tried to edit your question, please check it if correct. Just prefix the code parts with 4 spaces, no need for \` or `<code>`. You can click the "edit" button right below your question and see it.

Comment: Run `g++ -c main.cpp`, then `g++ -o hi main.o`, that might work

Comment: Code is correct. Command line is correct. There must be some configuration issue. These can be hard to solve here on Stack Overflow. Often you figure out what you need to add to the question to make it answerable by finding out what the problem was.

Comment: i tried using different gcc versions but still getting this error

Comment: Revised thinking: Command line is correct if the given code is in main.cpp. If it's not... All bets are off. Testing I get a very similar error message if I compile an empty main.cpp file.

Comment: Can you compile this code without vscode with g++ only: `g++ main.cpp`?

Comment: no i cant it shows the same error

Comment: Sounds like the `main.cpp` you're compiling *isn't* the one you're editing.  What does the output of `cat main.cpp` look like?  Is it what you'd expect?